# Suggestions for a word meaning both testimony and reminder?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What is a word that means both **testimony** and at the same time **reminder**?

Comment: Can you give more context, or maybe an example where it would be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Monument?  Memorial?  Or, if you want a Biblical flavor, from 1 Samuel 7:12, you could use "Ebenezer".

Comment: I like Ebenezer! the thing is I don't think a lot of people would understand it.

Comment: There's an old hymn called "Come Thou Font of Many Blessings" with the refrain "Here I raise my Ebenezer."  But the association for me was a rock song from the 80s - I could have sworn it was Midnight Oil, but I can't find a reference - that had absolutely nothing to do with the hymn, but had "I will raise my Ebenezer" as a refrain.  The song was running through my head when I saw your question.

Comment: Nice usage of Ebenezer. I have to confess that I would have been lost if I heard it without an explanation, but I like it.

Comment: Of course, when I hear "Ebenezer" I think of Scrooge...

Comment: I'm seated right now besides my colleague, and his name (really!) is Ebenezer! haha

Answer (score 4):

try [commemoration](http://www.wordnik.com/words/commemoration)

> –noun
>
> The act of commemorating or
>   calling to remembrance by some
>   solemnity; the act of honoring the
>   memory of some person or event by
>   solemn celebration: as, the feast of
>   the passover among the Israelites was
>   an annual commemoration of their
>   deliverance from Egypt.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility here is ***observance***

> –noun
>   1. an act or instance of following, obeying, or conforming to: the
>   observance of traffic laws.
>   2. a keeping or celebration by appropriate procedure, ceremonies,
>   etc.: the observance of the Sabbath.
>   3. a procedure, ceremony, or rite, as for a particular occasion: patriotic
>   observances.

Answer (score 1):

Or **eulogy**, **tribute**, or **homage**?  These suggestions all seem very mournful.